# Modify session MetadataBag lastUsed timestamp

Tags: symfony

I have implemented a listener to log the user out if idle for a certain amount of time, by using the 'lastUsed' property of the session metadatabag

```
public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
{
   $lastUsed = $event->getRequest()->getSession()->getMetadataBag()->getLastUsed();
  // redirect logic in case session idle for more than N minutes 

}
```

I now need a controller action (called from a functional test) to change the value of 'lastUsed' in order to have the above call returning a timestamp in past. Is that possible ? 
The property `MetadataBag::$lastUsed` is private

Answer (score 1):

I think you should create a session mock object http://api.symfony.com/3.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Storage/MockArraySessionStorage.html
and inject it instead real session for your unit tests and http://api.symfony.com/3.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Storage/MockFileSessionStorage.html for functional tests

Comment: thanks. I'll try that when I go back to it. The sw specs changed so I don't need that anymore